Trying to understand powershell syntax and why this is wrong
$filecontent.Replace ("["text_shadowYOffset"] = 0","["text_shadowXOffset"] = -2") | Set-Content -Path "D:\World of Warcraft\_classic_\WTF\Account\CRIXALIS\SavedVariables\WeakAuras.lua"

this keeps spitting out errors and i cannot even see what those errors are - any idea how to fix it?
I want to replace the shadowoffset text being changed from 0 to -2

hard to tell without seeing the actual errors :P but $fileContent.Replace ( is definitely a typo, the space between the method name and the opening parenthesis shouldn't be there. There is also a need to escape the inner " or use of ' as outer.

Cannot find an overload for "Replace" and the argument count: "1".
At C:\Users\Tommy\Desktop\WA Shadow Replace.ps1:7 char:1

$filecontent.Replace('["text_shadowXOffset"] = 0","["text_shadowXOffs ...

  + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest



.Replace('["text_shadowYOffset"] = 0','["text_shadowXOffset"] = -2')

No space before the parentheses and single quotes on the outside:
$filecontent = '["text_shadowYOffset"] = 0'
$filecontent.Replace('["text_shadowYOffset"] = 0', '["text_shadowXOffset"] = -2') 

["text_shadowXOffset"] = -2

Using -replace with regex, also escaping the opening square bracket with a backslash:
$filecontent -Replace '\["text_shadowYOffset"] = 0', '["text_shadowXOffset"] = -2'

